# How do I search files and folders by company certificate?

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-explorer

I am looking for an NVIDIA library. How can I search my PC for every file and folder with an NVIDIA certificate?

Answer (score 0):

There is no such tool, so you will have to write your own, probably as
a batch (`.bat`) or PowerShell script.

You may use as tool
[Sysinternals Sigcheck](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sigcheck)
that can dump a file's signature, then you can scan the folders you like.
Scanning the whole disk will take too long, although your script
can limit the check to executable files.

Here is the output for my file
`C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\Control Panel Client\NvGpuUtilization.exe`:

[image]

Comment: Write the script to scan whole disk for command certificate file extensions only should filter the scan and allow it to complete faster.